# django page not found when creating a register and sign up

Tags: python, django

I tries to fix this problem so many times but I get this error always and also I tired to make register page with django "404 page not found" any way this is some files in my code files in my code and also push this to git https://github.com/dtheekshanalinux/learnprogramming if don't mind go and check it out

index.html in templates

```
    {% load static %}
{% static "images" as baseUrl %}
<!doctype html>
<!-- Website Template by freewebsitetemplates.com -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mustache Enthusiast</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/mobile.css' %}" media="screen and (max-width : 568px)">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/mobile.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <a href="{% static 'index.html' %}" class="logo">
            <img src="{% static 'images/logo.jpg' %}" alt="">
        </a>
        <ul id="navigation">
            <li class="selected">
                <a href="{% static 'index.html' %}">home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{% static 'about.html' %}">about</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{% static 'accounts/register' %}">register</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{% static 'contact.html' %}">contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="body">
        <div id="featured">
            <img src="{% static 'images/the-beacon.jpg' %}" alt="">
            <div>
                <h2>the beacon to all mankind</h2>
                <span>Our website templates are created with</span>
                <span>inspiration, checked for quality and originality</span>
                <span>and meticulously sliced and coded.</span>
                <a href="{% static 'blog-single-post.html' %}" class="more">read more</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul>
            {% for cate in categos %}
            <li>
                <a href="{% static 'gallery.html' %}">
                    <img src="{{cate.img.url}}" alt="" style="width:240px;height:200px;">
                    <span>{{cate.name}}</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

register.html in templates

```
    {% load static%}
<!doctype html>
<!-- Website Template by freewebsitetemplates.com -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mustache Enthusiast</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/mobile.css' %}" media="screen and (max-width : 568px)">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/mobile.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <a href="{% static 'index.html' %}" class="logo">
            <img src="{% static 'images/logo.jpg' %}" alt="">
        </a>
        <ul id="navigation">
            <li class="selected">
                <a href="{% static 'index.html' %}">home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{% static 'about.html' %}">about</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{% static 'contact.html' %}">contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="body">
        <div id="featured">
            <img src="{% static 'images/the-beacon.jpg' %}" alt="">
            <div>
                <h2>Registration</h2>
                <form action="register" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First name"><br>
                    <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last name"><br>
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"><br>
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email"><br>
                    <input type="password" name="password1" placeholder="Password"><br>
                    <input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Confirm password"><br>
                    <input type="submit">
                </form>
                <a href="{% static 'blog-single-post.html' %}" class="more">read more</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

urls.py in learnprogramming

```
    """learnprogramming URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('',include('propython.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/',include('accounts.urls')),

]
urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

setting.py in learnprogramming

```
    """
Django settings for learnprogramming project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'ftc7ah)le3cvwx6c-pgmw(zhb3#33&t)s+*3n_pc2n^vn0_4fr'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'propython.apps.PropythonConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'learnprogramming.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'learnprogramming.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'learnprogramming',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'Nr@004507',
        'HOST': 'localhost',

    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets')


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

please definitely check the github because it more sense
thanks.

Comment: What is the url you have entered?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/   to view my web site I entered this url it shows the my home page but the problem is when I click the register button occurs a error 404 page ot found

Comment: if you can please check my github code https://github.com/dtheekshanalinux/learnprogramming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `{% static 'accounts/register' %}` with `{% url 'register' %}`
register is a view you have made in the accounts app not a static resource

Answer (score 0):

try adding / before url while submitting form

Answer (score 0):

DATABASES = { 'default': { 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',

}

}

In base.html

```
        <li>
            <a href="accounts/register">register</a>
        </li>
```

Comment: change your database setting

Comment: <ul id="navigation">
            <li class="selected">
                <a href="/">home</a>
            </li>
            
            <li>
                <a href="accounts/register">register</a>
            </li>
            
        </ul>